# Select TWO rows from table based on ONE row from another table

Tags: mysql

This is the query I have:

```
$query = "SELECT t1.one_field,t2.another_field FROM table_one t1,
table_two t2 WHERE t2.flag = 2 AND (t1.id = t2.id1 OR t1.id = t2.id2)
AND (t2.id1 = '$comparison' OR t2.id2 = '$comparison') LIMIT 1";
```

I tried with GROUP BY, DISTINCT, UNIQUE (...) but could never extract what I wanted... I always extract **another_field** and ONE **one_field** instead of TWO **one_field**... what is the best way to accomplish this? Tyvm...

### Table 1

```
one_field | id
example1 | id_example1
example2 | id_example2
```

### Table 2

```
another_field | flag | id1 | id2
need_to_get | 2 | id_example1 | id_example2
```

### What I want to get

```
example1, example2, need_to_get (don't care if result is array or associative)
```

### What I get

```
example2, need_to_get (expected, since one of the results gets overridden since it has the same field_name...)
```

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: Try adding the fields you want to the `select` clause.

Comment: @GordonLinoff ... well, of course? And aren't they already?

Comment: What do you mean by "one of the results gets overridden since it has the same field_name"? It looks to me like you're getting one result back because your query has "LIMIT 1" at the end. Remove that, and you'll get two rows.